Is there always a permuted tuple of $n+1$ elements such that multiplying elementwise$\bmod n + 1$ on $(0, 1, \ldots, n)$ yields a binary $n+1$ tuple?
Allow me to explain and give examples of something I've been playing around with.
Let $A$ be the $n+1$ tuple of the form $(0, 1, 2, \ldots, n)$. Let $k = n + 1$ be the number of elements.
My question is: is there a tuple $B$ which is a permutation of $A$ that when you multiply element-wise $AB \bmod k$ you get a binary tuple e.g. each element of the tuple $e_i \in \{0,1\}$?
An example is take $$A = (0,1,2), B = (0,1,2)$$ Then $$AB\bmod 3 = (0\cdot0, 1\cdot1, 2\cdot2) \bmod3 = (0, 1, 1)$$ since $0\cdot0 = 0\bmod3, 1\cdot1 = 1\bmod3, 2\cdot2=1\bmod3$.  Then this $B$ is a possible solution. Note that $$B = (0,2,1)$$ is not a solution since $$AB\mod{3} = (0\cdot0, 1\cdot2, 2\cdot1)\bmod3 = (0, 2, 2).$$ I have found that up to $k=9$ there is always a permutation. The amount of permutations vary and this is what I have so far for each $k$ using a brute force program:
$$1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 4, 7: 7, 8: 4, 9: 18.$$
An example solution for $k=9$ is to take the permutation $$A = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), B = (1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 8)$$ which results in $$AB\mod{9} = (0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1).$$
There are some things I can immediately see such as any element can work in the 0th place since it will be multiplied by 0. Whereas only 0 and 1 work in the 1st place. Finding the 0s will happen when $ab\mid k$ and the 1s when $ab$ is coprime to $k$.
What I do not know and would love help on is:

Is there always a permutation that works for any $k > 9$?
Is there a way to find the number of permutations possible for each $k$? Like a formula to describe the sequence of permutation counts?
Is there a way to generate a permutation without brute force?


Please use TeX for all mathematical formulae. That is, "$(n+1)$-tuple" instead of "n+1 tuple" etc. Also, explain what you mean by expressions like $2*2$.

@GHfromMO I've edited to have TeX for each math formula. I've also updated the example to be more clear. When I have the expression $2*2$ that is multiplication in the typical way of integers, then taking $\mod{k}$. So when I say $AB$ I am defining multiplying these tuples by multiplying each element by the ith element in the other tuple and taking $\mod{k}$ This means that for any $A,B$ being $k$ tuples their product $AB$ is also a $k$ tuple with every element being in the range of $0, k-1$

It is better to use standard notation, e.g. $2\cdot 2$ instead of $2*2$.

@GHfromMO I've corrected the multiplication notation. Thank you for all your feedback. It has been a few years since I was in academia using TeX.

Such a permutation exists if and only if $k$ is $1$, $6$, $8$, $p$, or $p^2$ for some prime $p$, and if so, one such permutation has a simple explicit description.
The cases $k=1,6,8$ are easy. If $k=p$ or $k=p^2$, we can use the permutation
$$\pi(x)=\begin{cases}x^{-1}&\gcd(x,k)=1,\\x&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
On the other hand, assume that $\pi$ is such a permutation for a given $k$. Then
$$p\ge\varphi(k/p)$$
for all prime factors $p\mid k$: there are $\varphi(k/p)$ elements $x$ such that $\gcd(x,k)=p$, and $\pi$ maps these elements injectively into the set of all elements $y$ such that $py\equiv0\pmod k$, the number of which is $p$.
If $k$ is not a prime power, let $p_1<p_2<\dots<p_l$, $l\ge2$, be its prime divisors; then
$$p_1\ge\varphi(k/p_1)\ge(p_2-1)\prod_{i>2}(p_i-1)>p_1$$
unless $l=2$ and $p_2-1=p_1$, i.e., $k=6$.
If $k=p^e$, $e\ge2$, then
$$p\ge\varphi(p^{e-1})=p^{e-2}(p-1)>p$$
unless either $e=2$, or $e=3$ and $p=2$, i.e., $k=8$.

Very nice! It's fun when a question actually has a complete answer.

No. For $n=14$ it's not possible. There are at most $\phi(15)=8$ ones modulo $15$ in the product, and thus a least $15-8=7$ zeros. However, each zero must result from the product of numbers at least one of which is divisible by 5. We have only 6 multiples of 5 in the two permutations and thus getting 7 zeros is not possible.

Thank you for your counter example. I now have a better understanding of finding possible solutions. Your answer makes me think there may be a max $k$ which has a permutation as described and any larger $k$ will not have one because increasing $k$ means "less supply" of zeros and ones.

@Jacob No, it's more complicated than that. E.g., such a permutation always exists when $k$ is prime.

@EmilJeřábek So I understand how when $k$ is prime you have "best possible chance" of finding a permutation because of the totient function argument above, but how is it known that you'll always have a permutation in this case? Could there not be some prime $k$ where an element $e$ in the tuple has only a couple choices $a,b$ s.t. $ae, eb = 1$ but $a,b$ are "taken"?

@Jacob: For prime $n+1$, just pair each non-zero element $m$ with $m^{-1}\bmod(n+1)$, and zero with zero.

Ah that makes it clear. Thank you!
